# Stop indeterminate progress bar android

Tags: android

My android application use `ProgressDialog`. When send http request to server (RESTFul Webservice) the dialog is showed, when receive result from server the dialog is hided

```
private class GetMyTimeSheetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        MyTimeSheetFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                progress = new ProgressDialog(MyTimeSheetFragment.this.getContext());
                progress.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                progress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
                progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progress.setCancelable(false);
                progress.show();
            }
        } );

        String result = HttpUtil.httpGet(
                params[0], params[1],
                params[2], params[3],
                params[4]);
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String param) {
        progress.dismiss();
        ....
        }
    }
```

The problem is sometime server has problem, the progress dialog is showed forever, i do not know how to close it. How to solve this problem? Thank for any help.

Comment: You can run your asyc in handler and in handler after certain seconds response is not received or null && progressdialog.isshowing() then cancel the dialog and show some error message

Answer (score 2):

Your HttpUtil should return an error message when error occur, and timeout information when time out, so you can hide the dialog when you receive these exception messages.
I can‘t see HttpUtil code, here maybe a solution so far:

```
private class GetMyTimeSheetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {  
    private static final int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private Runnable hideDialogTask = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
   };

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        MyTimeSheetFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(MyTimeSheetFragment.this.getContext());
            progress.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            progress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();
            handler.postDelayed(hideDialogTask, REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
        }
    } );

    String result = HttpUtil.httpGet(
            params[0], params[1],
            params[2], params[3],
            params[4]);
    return result;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String param) {
    progress.dismiss();
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: additionally, please check Activity's lifecycle when dismiss dialog :

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing a timeout scenario along with async task